# GroupBy using GremlinPipeline with OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, orientdb-2.1

I'm using the Java embedded version of OrientDB and I wanted to execute some gremlin queries.
So I'm using GremlinPipeline to do this.
I was wondering how to do a groupBy.

Say each vertice contains a property "age", I want to do a group by on this property.

I tried doing following :

```
List a = new GremlinPipeline(graphDb.getVertices()).groupBy(new PipeFunction<Vertex, String>() {
                                                            public String compute(Vertex vertex) {
                                                                   return "age";
                                                            }}, new PipeFunction<Vertex, Integer>() {
                                                            public Integer compute(Vertex vertex) {
                                                                   return vertex.getProperty("age");
                                                            }}).toList();
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

But it's returning me all the vertices instead.

How to group them and count the number of items inside a group according to the property "age" ?

Comment: Hi, could you also accept a Gremlin query to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**This is my code:**

[image]

**and this is the output:**

[image]

Hope it helps